# iphone native app in html/js interactivity

Tags: javascript, objective-c

Is it possible to communicate between Objective-C and JavaScript? Call a JavaScript function from Objective-C. Call Objective-C function from JavaScript? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UIWebView to host your html+javascript you can use the

```
 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
```

method to evaluate a javascript fragment (and call your JS functions from that).
Calling ObjC code from javascript would be complicated: for what I know you can only call JS code from ObjC, but not viceversa.
You could periodically call a certain JS function from ObjC and use the returned string to select some action to perform in ObjC.
Kind of hackish, I think, but I have no other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Use phonegap.

The main objective of phonegap is to allow js apps to be run on iphone devices.

IT essentially uses stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: as described above but has whole library of cool stuff that allows phonegap js classes to call native obj-c libraries. This means that these particular js functions run at obj-c speeds. The phonegap audio object is a good example.

However it has some nice features for going the extra mile. You can create your own custom obj-c functions with plugins and call these from js.

You can also call js from obj-c with:
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:'alert('Hello;'];

Note webView is a handle to the phonegap UIwebview.

You automatically get a handle on this in the phonegap plugins and the phonegap app delegate.

However not sure how to call it from non phonegap classes eg openfeint.

It's what I'm going to ask now.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of UIWebView's `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` delegate method.
At the point, from where you want to call the native method, prepare a fake URL like `fake://abc?par1=val1&par2=val2` and load the web view with fake request.
 The delegate method mentioned above will catch the request and there you can process the request on the basis of protocol. If it is fake then do whatever you want and return NO from delegate method, otherwise return YES to make normal loading of requests.